How to Get Negative Voltage with Virtual Ground for Differential OpAmp? (One power supply)
I am reading about working with virtual ground and generating negative voltage. I am trying to power a differential op amp circuit, and I expect some of these differences to result in a Vout that is negative. Because of this, I wanted to bias my op amp with +5V and -5V.
I only have a positive voltage source, and I am using TinkerCAD to simulate this. I read that I can use things like charge pumps, but I was wondering if it would be possible to implement a virtual ground as a reference ground and anything below this reference point would be negative. So this would make actual ground (0V), be interpreted as -5V, if my virtual ground was 5V and my power supply was 10V.
In the first picture, I take two power supplies and put them in series with each other to establish a virtual ground. This seemed to work well, since 5V - 3.3V = 1.7V in the Vout as expected, but I wanted to try to do this with only one power supply

In this second picture, I created a virtual ground (5V) using a voltage divider and two capacitors in parallel (schematic I found online is attached below). I then set the ground of another breadboard to be this new reference, and it seems like the rails are measuring +/-5V as expected.

However, when I connect two voltage sources to then use the differential amplifier (3.3V and 5V), I get a change in voltage readings across all of the rails and I am not sure why, I'd like them to be stable.

I am wondering if someone can help me figure out the issue, or guide me on what steps I should take to troubleshoot. I appreciate any help!
If helpful, this is the differential op amp circuit I was trying to implement:

Referenced from another stackexchange post:
How to Calculate Op-Amp Level Shift for differential amp and gain of 2
And this is the capacitor and resistors voltage divider circuit I was following online:

Referenced from learnelectronics on YouTube at time [2:56]:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CaPmKfBhDk&ab_channel=learnelectronics

The impedance of your artificial (nothing virtual about it) ground is 5 kOhm although it  needs to be 0 Ohm at DC for the differential amp to work as expected. These 5 kOhm are in series with Rg which is why you get strange but correct voltage readings. Add another op amp with unity gain that buffers the 5V from the resistive divider.

Also, you cannot read output current/voltage with a charge pump. Use a multimeter. A charge pump only boosts the voltage.

At the risk of making things look even more complicated, I'll offer some insights that might help. I'll redraw the differential amplifier with some changes. The bottom end of \$R_g\$ is connected to 0V ground in your question, but it could actually be connected to any source of potential. Here I will call that potential \$V_3\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If node 3 were grounded (as in your schematic), so that \$V_3=0V\$, and assuming that \$R_f=R_g\$ and \$R_1=R_2\$, the formula stated in your diagram is still true:
$$ V_{OUT} = \frac{R_f}{R_1}(V_2 - V_1) $$
Accounting now for the case where node 3 is not grounded, \$V_3 \ne 0V\$, we have a more general formula:
$$ V_{OUT} = \frac{R_f}{R_1}(V_2 - V_1) + V_3 $$
I have removed all references to ground. There are only arbitrary potentials \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$. The remarkable thing about this is that I can add any offset \$V_X\$ to all of them, without breaking that relationship:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} +V_X &= \frac{R_f}{R_1}\left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}(V_2 + V_X)- (V_1+V_X)\right] + (V_3 + V_X) \\ \\
&= \frac{R_f}{R_1}\left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}(V_2 + V_X -  V_1 - V_X)\right] + V_3 + V_X \\ \\
&= \frac{R_f}{R_1}(V_2 -  V_1) + V_3 + V_X \\ \\
V_{OUT} &= \frac{R_f}{R_1}(V_2 - V_1) + V_3 \\ \\
\end{aligned} 
$$
I am trying to show that if all the potentials were to rise (or fall) by, say +100V, the behaviour of this circuit doesn't change. The only change is what you call "zero volts".
Let's see that in practice, by literally adding 100V to every signal and power supply potential:

simulate this circuit
Note that the op-amp's power supplies are 10V above the new "fake ground" of +100V, and 10V below it, so that the op-amp is able to produce any output potential in the range +90V to +110V, and will behave as expected with any potential at its inverting and non-inverting inputs within that same range.
Since we have gain \$\frac{R_f}{R_1}=\frac{10k\Omega}{5k\Omega}=2\$, we should expect the output to be two times the difference \$V_2 - V_1\$, and offset by +100V.
There's nothing stopping you from "centering" all potentials anywhere you want. For example, if you have a 10V source as a power supply, and you arbitrarily call its negative terminal 0V, then the positive terminal must be +10V. Since your op-amp's inputs and outputs are constrained to that same range, it might be appropriate to "center" all the signals (which we call "biasing") exactly half way between them, at +5V. Then your situation would resemble this:

simulate this circuit
\$V_{OFS1}\$, \$V_{OFS2}\$ and \$V_3\$ simply "raise" all signal potentials (including the output) by 5V. This is inconvenient if you don't have a source of +5V, but interestingly, if you have two 5V sources connected in series (for 10V total), and you have access to their junction, that very same circuit looks like this:

simulate this circuit
There's no need for any +5V sources, because the junction of Va and Vb has exactly that potential. Now let's move the ground symbol, which is just a declaration of the node we would like to arbitrarily declare as having "zero volts", and we have this:

simulate this circuit
Algebraically, all the potentials are 5V lower, but physically nothing changed.
I don't think I've answered your question per se, but there are some pointers here that might help you better understand what "biasing" actually means, and how dual supplies can help with that.
In particular, dual supplies provide you with a rigid (low source impedance) "zero volts" reference, which makes for a great \$V_3 = 0V\$, as you can see in that last schematic. Consider, though, what happens if your source of \$V_3\$ isn't so rigid, and is instead a rather flexible mid-point potential, provided perhaps by a somewhat weak resistor voltage divider. Any load on that source (sourcing or sinking current to/from it) will influence the potential there, and will necessarily mess up the maths. Therefore it is essential that the source of \$V_3\$ have as low a source impedance as possible. That's why we often see a supply mid-point potential produced with a resistor voltage divider, but also buffered by a voltage follower, which has near-zero source impedance:

simulate this circuit
Other stages and modules (for instance amplifiers, inverting and non-inverting) can employ that same +5V source (as long as they don't overload OA2's output current limit, typically 10mA or so), thereby all operating around that same bias point, all having their input and output signals offset from ground by the same amount, all agreeing about where "center" is.

A fascinating approach to convincing others about the relativity of the concept of "ground"...

In your circuit the current passing through Rg will affect the voltage Vg at the voltage divider. The Thevenin equivalent source resistance is R/2 so if you have 10kΩ resistors as shown in your pictorial diagram the source Z is 5kΩ. That will reduce the gain from V2 quite significantly, leaving the gain from V1 unaffected. You could forget the divider and replace Rg with two 20k resistors, one from the input to each supply, then the output would be 5V for 0V differential input.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For the circuit shown above, the output voltage is V2+5V and V3 cancels out, over some range.
You could also buffer the 'virtual ground' voltage with another op-amp, and that will work well at DC, however op-amps have significant output resistance for AC. You can add some circuitry to reduce that but it has to be a bit more complex than just capacitors, which will cause most op-amps to be unstable. There are 'rail splitter' ICs that are designed for this task, however it's probably cheaper to add a -5V supply.
It's often better to add a charge pump like the 7660 since that will allow you to have a solid ground that is common with your MCU, and the exact values of your power supply voltages don't affect the output voltage significantly.

I have redrawn Spehro's schematic and added a DC sweep simulation. Schematic, CircuitLab simulation, DC sweep

What you are looking for is called a "rail splitter". It takes a single-ended voltage supply and provides an output that "splits" the difference, providing a ground.
The simplest version of a rail splitter is a simple op-amp with a voltage divider providing half the supply voltage at the non-inverting input, and the inverting input set up as a voltage follower, like so

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The major shortcoming of this rail splitter is that it has very limited current capability.
The current capability can be increased with push-pull pair of transistors to boost the current.
Here is the basic form, but there are many improvements that can be made. I'm not going to show them all. Perhaps someone else will show some other options.

simulate this circuit
However, I would also like to suggest a third option, which can give you significant current, and may also have significant other advantages. That is to use an audio amplifier IC.

simulate this circuit
Although the TDA2050 is obsolete in the US, it is manufactured in plentiful supply in China, is quite robust, and inexpensive, and with a heatsink is rated to handle over 3 amps of output current.
R3, R4 and C3 are needed for stability, as the TDA2050 is not unity gain stable. However, the charging of C3 may result in a lopsided "split" as the circuit powers up. If this is an issue, you may want to add some more circuitry.
C4 and R5 may not be necessary. They implement a low pass filter that is present in virtually all audio amps of this topology. Since the output voltage is ideally a constant value half way between the rails, such a filter may be redundant. I have kept this filter in place in case it adds something to the stability of the circuit.
C1 and C2 should be as close to the TDA2050 as possible.
There are commercially available modules implementing this circuit with extra components. In particular, these modules contain an output capacitor that must be removed or bypassed if the module is to be used for rail splitting rather than audio amplification. These modules generally also come with a potentiometer, input capacitors etc. which do nothing for this application, but don't hurt if they are left in place.
Be aware that the pins of a TDA2050 do not fit in a standard solderless breadboard in any reasonable way. So, for prototyping, it is easiest to simply remove/bypass the output cap on a pre-made module.
